# R ggplot2 color mapping with geom_hline

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-hline

I am trying to map color variable to geom_hline, but doesn't seem to work like other geometries. Neither of these work, in each case, rendering a fixed black line.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=0,y=0,series="ABC"),aes(x,y,color=series))) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,show.legend = TRUE)

ggplot(data.frame(x=0,y=0),aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,aes(color="ABC"),show.legend = TRUE)
```

Is this a bug, or is there some syntax I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to set aesthetics for the `geom_hline()` then also `yintercept=` should be put in `aes()` call.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=0,y=0,series="ABC"),aes(x,y,color=series)) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0,color=series))

ggplot(data.frame(x=0,y=0),aes(x,y)) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0,colour="ABC"))
```